# Adding nodes to json in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to generate custom JSON in python using the following code

```
root={}
Levels=[['L1','L1','L2'],
        ['L1','L1','L3'],
        ['L1','L2'],
        ['L2','L2','L3'],
        ['L2','L2','L1'],
        ['L3','L2'],
        ['L4','L2','L1'],
        ['L4','L2','L4']]

def append_path(root, paths):
    if paths:
        child = root.setdefault(paths[0], {})
        append_path(child, paths[1:])

for p in Levels:
    append_path(root, p)

def convert(d):
    templist=[]
    noofchildren=0
    if(len(d.items())==0):
        return ([{}],1)
    for k,v in d.items():
        temp,children=convert(v)
        noofchildren+=children
        if(temp):
            templist.append({"name":k+"("+str(children)+")",'children':temp})
        else:
            templist.append({'name': k+"("+str(children)+")", 'children':[{}]})

    return (templist,noofchildren)    

# Print results
import json
print(json.dumps(convert(root)[0],  indent=2))
```

and the OUTPUT is

```
[
  {
    "name": "L1(3)",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "L1(2)",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "L2(1)",
            "children": [
              {}
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "L3(1)",
            "children": [
              {}
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "L2(1)",
        "children": [
          {}
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "L2(2)",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "L2(2)",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "L3(1)",
            "children": [
              {}
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "L1(1)",
            "children": [
              {}
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "L3(1)",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "L2(1)",
        "children": [
          {}
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "L4(2)",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "L2(2)",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "L1(1)",
            "children": [
              {}
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "L4(1)",
            "children": [
              {}
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My dataset has changed a little bit

```
 Levels=[[['L1','L1','L2'],[10,20,30]],
        [[['L1','L1','L3'],[10,15,20]],
        [[['L1','L2'],[20,10]],
        [[['L2','L2','L3'],[20,20,30]],
        [[['L2','L2','L1'],[10,20,30]]
        [[['L3','L2'],[10,20]]
        [[['L4','L2','L1'],[10,20,10]]
        [[['L4','L2','L4'],[20,40,50]]]
```

and the output that I want is the average of the levels along with the count

```
[
  {
    "name": "L1(3)#(13)", // taking avg of 10,10,20
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "L1(2)#(17)", // taking avg of 20,15
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "L2(1)#(30)",
            "children": [
              {}
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "L3(1)#(20)",
            "children": [
              {}
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "L2(1)#10",
        "children": [
          {}
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "L2(2)#(15)", // avg of 20,10
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "L2(2)#(20)", // avg of 20,20
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "L3(1)#(30)",
            "children": [
              {}
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "L1(1)#(30)",
            "children": [
              {}
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "L3(1)#(10)",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "L2(1)#(10)",
        "children": [
          {}
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "L4(2)#(15)",// avg of 10,20
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "L2(2)#(30)", // avg of 20,40
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "L1(1)# (10)",
            "children": [
              {}
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "L4(1)#(50)",
            "children": [
              {}
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How can i change my code to add this information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Preface

Before moving onto the solution, here are some points I want to mention:

- *Make use of Python's object-oriented programming features*! This makes the data structure much clearer to both yourself and future readers.
- Using a custom class also makes it easier for us to store the metadata – i.e. the number of instances of a node and its total value – while **constructing** the intermediate tree structure, rather than while **converting** it. This is also more efficient because with the latter method, a simple naive traversal algorithm would make duplicate visits to the nodes!
- If you want your output to (reliably) maintain the order in which the paths were inserted, you should use an **`OrderedDict`** (from `collections`) instead of an ordinary `dict` (`{}`).
- It is more logical to output an empty list for nodes with no children than a list with a single empty dict:

  ```
  // Before
  "children": [
    {}
  ]

  // After
  "children": []
  ```

  The reason being that any software which will parse this data later can safely assume that all objects have the `"name"` and `"children"` fields, which an empty dict does not.
- The list boundaries and elements in the `Levels` array seem to be poorly formed; did you mean:

  ```
  Levels = [
      [['L1','L1','L2'],[10,20,30]],
      [['L1','L1','L3'],[10,15,20]],
      [['L1','L2'],[20,10]],
      [['L2','L2','L3'],[20,20,30]],
      [['L2','L2','L1'],[10,20,30]],
      [['L3','L2'],[10,20]],
      [['L4','L2','L1'],[10,20,10]],
      [['L4','L2','L4'],[20,40,50]],
  ]
  ```
- While on the subject of the data, since the nodes and values obey 1-to-1 mappings (within each path), it would be more appropriate to use a **list of tuples** rather than a list of two parallel lists:

  ```
  Levels = [
      [('L1', 10), ('L1', 20), ('L2', 30)],
      [('L1', 10), ('L1', 15), ('L3', 20)],
      [('L1', 20), ('L2', 10)],
      [('L2', 20), ('L2', 20), ('L3', 30)],
      [('L2', 10), ('L2', 20), ('L1', 30)],
      [('L3', 10), ('L2', 20)],
      [('L4', 10), ('L2', 20), ('L1', 10)],
      [('L4', 20), ('L2', 40), ('L4', 50)]
  ]
  ```
- There seems to be a mistake in your expected output:

  ```
  {
    "name": "L3(1)#(10)",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "L2(1)#(10)", <--- this should be #(20)
        "children": [
          {}
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  ```

---

### Implementations

- For your current data format (pair of lists):

  ```
  # A dictionary here corresponds to an array of nodes in JSON
  # the "name" fields serve as the keys and "children" as the values
  class data_node(OrderedDict):
      def __init__(self, **kwargs):
          super(data_node, self).__init__(**kwargs)
          self.instances = 0
          self.total = 0

      def insert(self, names, values):
          # Python lists are truthy, so no need for len(path) == 0
          if not (names or values):
              return

          # create the child node if it doesn't exist
          child = self.get(names[0], data_node())

          # add the value to the total
          # and increment the instance counter
          child.instances += 1
          child.total += values[0]

          # recursive call on the child 
          # with the rest of the path
          child.insert(names[1:], values[1:])
          self[names[0]] = child

      def convert(self):
          return [
              {
                  "name": "{}({})#({})".format(
                      name,
                      child.instances,
                      child.total / child.instances # mean
                  ),
                  "children": child.convert()
              }
              for name, child in self.items()
          ]

  tree = data_node()
  for path in Levels:
      tree.insert(path[0], path[1])
  print json.dumps(tree.convert(), indent=2)
  ```
- For my proposed data format (list of tuples):

  ```
  # only the insertion method differs
  # all other parts of the class are unchanged
  def insert(self, path):
      if not path:
          return
      name, value = path[0]
      child = self.get(name, data_node())
      child.instances += 1
      child.total += value
      child.insert(path[1:])
      self[name] = child

  ...

  for path in Levels:
      tree.insert(path) # simpler function signature
  ```

**EDIT**:

If there is a reason that you want the leaf node format to be `[{}]` instead of just `[]`, only a simple change would be needed:

```
# in convert()
{
    "name": ..., # as before

    # again exploiting the truthy-ness property of arrays
    "children": child.convert() or [{}] 
}
```

---

### Output

Both implementations give the correct JSON output, according my comments in the preface:

```
[
  {
    "name": "L1(3)#(13)",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "L1(2)#(17)",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "L2(1)#(30)",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "L3(1)#(20)",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "L2(1)#(10)",
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "L2(2)#(15)",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "L2(2)#(20)",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "L3(1)#(30)",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "L1(1)#(30)",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "L3(1)#(10)",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "L2(1)#(20)",
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "L4(2)#(15)",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "L2(2)#(30)",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "L1(1)#(10)",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "L4(1)#(50)",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would also like to add a threshold value to the child.instances. I want to eliminate child.instances that are less than some value x. Where can i add that ?

Comment: @Rohit very simple - in `convert` after the for-loop line `for name, child in self.items()`, add `if child.instances >= x`; this is an example of conditional list comprehension.